# Multibranch pipeline with only the last 5 used branches

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In our company, we already configure Jenkins multibranch pipelines with a small project we are working now. We love this pipelines but now we have only 20 branches but the will grow up fastly to thousands and now we are only building but in next weeks we wanted to add deploy in a docker container for each one.

We want to filter and use only the last ones used and the other should not be listed or executed anymore:

We have different options (but I would like to avoid):

- Find a naming convention to make it in order (not possible with our currently naming). And over that filtering over name
- Delete the branches that we are not using anymore.

there is something to filter over the last used 5-10 branches to run only this ones?

Comment: i'd delete the branches in source control that you're no longer using if that's an option.

Comment: It is an option but it will make us to check every branch that is not used to be manually deleted. 
I am looking for another option